Received an email from my company includes revert with 6 months contract extension
My seaman boyfriend received an email says please be so kind to revert with 6 months contract extension he is under probation period. What does it mean?

We wouldn't know what that means. Have him ask his manager or boss.

I also suspect there is an English-as-a-second-language issue here. "Please be so kind to revert" is not the phrasing used in any contract discussion I've ever been involved in.

@PhilipKendall It could very well be perfectly fine Indian English. It is a (slightly) different language.

Which country is this? If this is USA or UK, then the words "revert with 6 months contract extension" don't make any sense.
If it is in India, then I would assume that they are offering him a six month extension of his contract, which means he has finished his probabition period successfully.
Now my Indian English isn't good enough to be hundred percent sure of this - but with the words "to be kind enough" this is the most likely interpretation, and in a situation like this, if you are not 100% sure you should assume the more positive interpretation.
So if your boyfriend wants the six month contract extension, he should reply that he would be happy to extend the contract, and what to do to accept the contract extension.

In the UK and Ireland, sometimes in a business context "revert" is used to mean "reply". The sentence is oddly phrased, but I agree that they want your boyfriend to confirm that he would like to have his contract extended. They may want to make sure he's interested before they proceed with the paperwork.
